# Failed to create *.vec file when using opencv_createsamples.exe

Tags: opencv, cascade

I am trying to run opencv_createsamples.exe to generate .vec file. When I try to load in a collection of images, there is an error

`Unable to open image: pos/pos.txt
 pos/pos.txt(1):parse errorDone. Create 0 samples`.

I indicate the number as 100, but still there are parse error, I am not sure what is going wrong here? Any help is appreciated!

Here is my pos.txt file:

```
pos.txt
1.png
2.png
3.png
```

command line call:

```
`opencv_createsamples.exe -vec pos.vec -info pos/pos.txt -bg neg/neg.txt -w 63 -h 63 -num 100`
```

Comment: `pos.txt` doesn't look like a filename of an image... The file passed in `-info` should only list images.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem! The problem is the pos.txt file should have the name exact the same with my images and should contain the information of ROI.
So finally, it looks like this:

```
1.vlcsnap-2015-12-24-15h28m51s637.png_0000_0124_0041_0063_0063.png 1 0 0 63 63
2.vlcsnap-2015-12-24-15h28m51s637.png_0000_0144_0178_0063_0063.png 1 0 0 63 63
```

1 0 0 63 63 is what I added to indicate the region of the image.
And the content before that is the name of images